# Accessing the Receiving Object that Throws an Exception

Tags: ruby, exception

While debugging a really strange issue with ActionMailer, I came to realize I didn't know how to access an object that was creating the exception. Not the exception, but the object itself.

```
begin
  AppMailer.send_invoice(hostel_resident).deliver_later
  flash[:success] = "Your invoice was sent successfully!"
rescue => msg 
  # display the system generated error message  
  flash[:error] = "#{msg}" 
end  

NoMethodError: undefined method `disposition_type' for #<Mail::UnstructuredField:0x009g71c2a68258>
```

This code works great to catch any exceptions and print the message.

However, how do I get ahold of the `<Mail::UnstructuredField:0x009g71c2a68258>` object? I'd like to be able to play around with this guy, read messages inside it, and just generally have access to it.

This has to be possible, but `inspect` doesn't help, `cause` is no use and `backtrace` just shows you where it happened. I need that object though, the receiver of the nonexistent method.

Thanks!

actionmailer (4.2.4)
mail (2.6.3)

Comment: Be wary of `raise Exception`.  Almost always you want to raise an exception that has `StandardError` in its ancestor chain. See, for example, [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception).

Comment: Thanks for the great link Cary. ThoughtBot is always great reading.

Comment: Never ever use `Exception` class in `rescue`. Check [this](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html)

Comment: All changed up to better reflect your comments. Anyone know how to get ahold of the receiving object though?

Comment: Actually, there's no need to write `StandardError`, its a default class if no class is provided in `rescue`. :)

Comment: Okay. Just fixed it up.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, using `receiver` on [`NameError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NameError.html) (which [`NoMethodError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NoMethodError.html) is a child of)

```
obj = Object.new
puts obj.to_s

begin
  obj.do_something
rescue NoMethodError => e
  puts e.message
  puts e.receiver
end

# #<Object:0x007fa5ac84da88>
# undefined method `do_something' for #<Object:0x007fa5ac84da88>
# #<Object:0x007fa5ac84da88>
```

This seems to require ruby >= 2.3, to do this for < 2.3, AFAIK you have to do something like this (not tested in older rubies, but *should* work):

```
class MyNoMethodError < NoMethodError
  attr_accessor :my_receiver
end

obj = Object.new
puts obj.to_s

begin
  begin
    obj.do_something
  rescue NoMethodError => e
    # rescue the exception and wrap it in the method that caused it, using `self` instead of `obj`
    error = MyNoMethodError.new(e)
    error.my_receiver = obj
    raise error
  end
rescue MyNoMethodError => c
  puts c.inspect        # custom exception stuff
  puts c.cause.inspect  # original exception stuff
  puts c.my_receiver
end

# #<Object:0x007f884e846d58>
# #<MyNoMethodError: undefined method `do_something' for #<Object:0x007f884e846d58>>
# #<NoMethodError: undefined method `do_something' for #<Object:0x007f884e846d58>>
# #<Object:0x007f884e846d58>
```

Comment: Weird, what ruby are you using? Going through previous ruby versions on the page I linked, the method is in 2.4, 2.3 and not 2.2, so it was added something after 2.2 before (or during) 2.3

Comment: Can't recreate `NoMethodError: undefined method `receiver' for #<NoMethodError:0x007fd0a4e9d488>`

Comment: I'm at 2.2.3 right now. Makes sense why it wasn't working.

Comment: @PatrickJones updated my answer, with a way to get it working < 2.3, though it's not as pretty and requires catching the exception inside the method that throws it, wrapping it, and then throwing the new one (I assume this happens somewhere in `send_invoice` which should allow you to just `rescue` at the end

Comment: You got my vote. Any chance you could answer the question above about how MS Outlook can affect a Rails app?

Comment: Unfortunately no clue, Haven't done much with mailers in rails or with MS Outlook in a few years now

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail). This is a known issue which is already reported in the GitHub. See [#851](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/851).

Try using different version of the gem, something in 2.6 series.

Comment: I read that article earlier today. What I don't understand is, how is it possible that MS Outlook can effect the attachments that my server is producing? If he is using my app on his computer and sending PDF invoices to his customers, all passing through my apps sender email address, how does him using MS Outlook have any bearing on my application? One user, that uses MS Outlook, is getting this error.  No one else is.